# Error creating image heroku ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Thanks for helping, i'm newe in ruby on rails and heroku. 
I'm trying to create an image in my app in ruby on rails i got the error We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

Having this in my heroku logs:

```
2014-11-16T21:17:47.163024+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"YGAFGhc/bbArC1y9wLamJxgYj6PKj+6OpnLrmc5gL+0=", "dream"=>
{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcdebb9a788 @tempfile=#
<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141116-2-rjk84j>, 
@original_filename="10608362_365147563650660_8385659019628098568_o.png", 
@content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;  
name=\"dream[image]\"; 
filename=\"10608362_365147563650660_8385659019628098568_o.png\"\r\nContent-Type: 
image/png\r\n">, "dream"=>"dream"}, "commit"=>"Create Dream"}
```

I can't understand where is the error. Any ideas of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't support the upload to the file-system. Your app is completely distributed across several machines, therefore the image you save will not be available when a second request is handled by a different process.

In Heroku you need to upload to a third-party storage, for example Amazon S3 or a cloud drive. Here's an article explaining [how to use Paperclip with Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3).